# How to set a content size of UIScrollView using stroyboard(!)?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, interface-builder, contentsize

[image]How to set a content size of UIScrollView using stroyboard(!) ?

I have a lot of scrollviews, so I don't want to set size of evry one programmaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IB settings for this.

- Click on the UIScrollView you want to set the content size
- Go to the identity inspector in the utilities pane on the right of interface builder

Under "User defined runtime attributes

- Click on the `+` button to add a new keyPath
- For `keyPath` column type in `contentSize`
- For  `type` column change it to `size`
- For `value` column change it to your desired content size value. e.g.: for a width of 320 and height of 600, write  `{ 320, 600 }`

**Edit**:

Here is a screen shot of it in Xcode 5

http://i41.photobucket.com/albums/e282/RobBob3/ScreenShot2014-02-15at94908PM.png

Comment: For which version of Xcode should it work? You know, I have the last version, so it's a bit different from the previous

Comment: The latest version is what it will work with. It was in Xcode 4 too and iOS5/6  Also, you should be using Xcode 5 which using iOS7 SDK. Apple won't accept any app submitted to the store with Xcode 4 or lower.

Comment: All is done exactly as you wrote but my app even crashes after this (only when I go this ViewController with ScrollView) 
Should I do something else, maybe? Is it the only one thing I schould write to make it working?

Comment: The app won't crash due to incorrect content size of a UIScrollView - there is another reason for the app crashing. What does the debugger say?

Comment: well, it didn't crash before. I will add an image - look above

Comment: In my answer I posted an image of what I was taking about. However there is an error - under type I have Range. It should be size. Sorry about that.